# Exiting shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have two shell script `abc.sh` and `def.sh`. `abc.sh` executes `def.sh` inside it and the control comes back to `abc.sh` through a return statement.

I have an echo command followed by an exit command which is apparently not working.

Below you will see content for `abc.sh`

```
sleep 60;
bash ./gen_files/def.sh ./gen_files/regress_rpt_1_0.txt
sleep 60;
bash ./gen_files/def.sh ./gen_files/regress_rpt_1_1.txt
sleep 10;
echo "COMPLETED **** EXITING NOW ****";
exit 0;
```

Please find the content for def.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function build_status()
              {
                FILE=$1
                if test -f "$FILE"; then
                  echo "$FILE File Exists"
                  if `grep -q "Build Job" $FILE`;then
                    echo "Build found,Continuing to next launch statement"
                    return
                  else
                    echo "Build Not Found,Waiting for the build"
                    sleep 120
                    build_status $FILE
                  fi
                else
                  echo "$FILE Not Found"
                  #build_status $FILE
                fi
              }
            FILE=$1
            build_status $FILE
```

I expect the script to exit after the print `COMPLETED **** EXITING NOW ****` and come back to terminal. However what I am seeing now is the script doesn't exit by its own. I can see the print in the terminal and shell script is still running with no activity

Comment: Welcome to the site. In what way is the script "not working"? Can you post example output? BTW, why do you start a new `bash` for the call to `def.sh`?

Comment: What's not working? What are you observing and what are you expecting to observe? Note that  `return` statements are only used to return from shell functions and from dot-scripts (scripts executed with the `.` or `source` commands).

Comment: @siva: def.sh searches for a string lets say "HAPPY" inside regress_1_0.txt, if the search is successful it returns to abc.sh

Comment: @siva: Added the content for def.sh as requested

Comment: @Siva; Yes it will, but the pattern will be always present.It is just a matter of time when it appears in the regress_rpt_1_0.txt which gets generated parallelly through another code

Comment: @siva: the problem here is i am not able to exit the shell script abc.sh even after the print COMPLETED **** EXITING NOW ****

Comment: @Avinash How are you running the `abc.sh` script? Are you running it as a background job from an interactive shell?

Comment: @kusalananda : yes i am running abc.sh as a background job

Comment: @Avinash So pressing `Enter` once would give you a prompt?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks, Pressing ENTER gave the prompt, is there a way I can get prompt without pressing ENTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run `abc.sh` as a background job.  This means that the output of the script (and the `def.sh` script) would be printed to the terminal while the `abc.sh` script is running in the background.

When the script is done, it will terminate.

The fact that you're running the script in the background and that it outputs to the terminal means that it will overwrite the prompt that the shell immediately prints after starting the script.  A new prompt will not be outputted by the shell until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The solution is to either write the output of the script to a log file,

```
./abc.sh >abc.log 2>&1 &
```

(this writes both output and errors to `abc.log` which will be created if it does not exist, or emptied if it does exist) or, to simply not run the script in the background,

```
./abc.sh
```